# parse json string using simple-json

Tags: java, json-simple

I have read the posts that appeared to be the same as my question but I must be missing something.  My environment is Eclipse Mars.  My JAVA is 1.7 and I have imported json-simple.  I simply wish to parse the json that is returned from my web service.  I control the web service if I need to modify its output.  I see the json in `arg[0]` as noted below however the Object obj is null as of course is the `JSONArray` array.  I know that I am missing something basic but I am stumped and a bit tired.

**Here is the returned json:**

```
[{"$id":"1","NumberID":121183,"PortfolioID":718,"PropertyID":14489,"Adsource":17287,"PlanTypeID":1,"GreetingFile":"HolidayGreeting.wav","PromptFile1":"senior.leasing.first.wav","Accepts1":2,"PromptAction_ID1":1,"PromptFile2":"Default.wav","Accepts2":2,"PromptAction_ID2":1,"PromptFile3":"Default.wav","Accepts3":2,"PromptAction_ID3":1,"PromptFile4":"Default.wav","Accepts4":2,"PromptAction_ID4":1,"PromptFile5":"Default.wav","Accepts5":2,"PromptAction_ID5":1,"HoldMsgFile1":"SpectrumHold.wav","HoldMsgFile2":"Default.wav","Destination1":15197,"Destination2":15024,"Destination3":0,"UIType_ID":16,"RingCount":0,"Enabled":true,"Spanish":false,"HoldMusicFile":"Hold_Music.wav","Template_ID":41,"FrontLineForward":true,"DisclaimerFIle":"1Silence.wav"}]
```

Here is the parse code employing json-simple:

```java
package parser;
import org.json.simple.*;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.*;

public class JsonParser 
{
    private static JSONObject _jsonInput;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //TODO

       try{
           JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
           Object obj = JSONValue.parse(args[0]);
           JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
           String name = array.get(3).toString();
           System.out.println(obj);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of the array different than the index used

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(args[1]));
JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
if (array.size() > 3)
  String name = array.get(3).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you Roman for your reply.  The string to be parsed is in args[0].  Iam now getting a "FileNotFound" error.

Comment: I hit RETURN by mistake so here is the rest of my question: I am passing in the result of a WebApi call which is a Json string.  Can Json-Simple take a string instead of a file?